# JOOQ JSON-ResultSet

Tags: java, jdbc, jooq

I have a Java application which used to fetch data from MySql database using JDBC and ResultSet. I had a DB communication subsystem that would receive name of the stored procedure to execute, list of arguments and simply return "ResultSet" containing all requested data.

Now, i want to start using JOOQ, but instead of changing this huge application on every place database results are processed, i would prefer to just JOOQ-ize part of the system in charge of direct database communication. That means, from "outside" (rest of the system) everything should seem the same - procedure receives name of the stored procedure to execute and list of arguments, JOOQ does it's thing and returns ResultSet to retain full compatibility.

I know how to convert ResultSet into JSON using JOOQ, but do you know how to convert JSON JOOQ provided me with to ResultSet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to convert JSON JOOQ provided me with to ResultSet?

I'm assuming you mean jOOQ's JSON export format that is documented here:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/exporting/exporting-json

You can re-import it easily again into a jOOQ [`Result`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html) using [`DSLContext.fetchFromJSON()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#fetchFromJSON-java.lang.String-), and then, the `Result` can be wrapped into a JDBC `ResultSet` through [`Result.intoResultSet()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#intoResultSet--):

```
ResultSet rs = ctx.fetchFromJSON(json).intoResultSet();
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks! Would it be possible without DSLContext? In ideal case, i would have JOOQ part on the server side, sending JSON formatted db data to remote client which (in ideal case) wouldn't need to re-establish DB connection for purpose of this conversion. The only problem i see with this is that in order to use DSLContext, i have to open a db connection, right? I can't use no "dummy" context?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid the `DSLContext`? If this is about not being connected, just write `DSL.using(sqldialect)` or even `DSL.using(new DefaultConfiguration())` and you got a "detached" `DSLContext`